# RDash - getting error while refresh the page and Upload the csv file

Tags: r, plotly-dash, plotly-dashr

This is Dash-R code for Uploading csv file.

Following Error I while refresh the page:

- **error: non-character argument**

**request: 127.0.0.1 - ID_127.0.0.1 [15/Jul/2020:22:22:38 +0530] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://127.0.0.1:8050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"**

while i am uploading csv file, i am getting following Error"

- **error: could not find function "base64_dec"**

**request: 127.0.0.1 - ID_127.0.0.1 [15/Jul/2020:22:23:08 +0530] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://127.0.0.1:8050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"**

```
library(dash)
library(dashCoreComponents)
library(dashHtmlComponents)
library(dashTable)

app <- Dash$new()

app$layout(htmlDiv(list(
  dccUpload(
    id='upload-data',
    children=htmlDiv(list(
      'Drag and Drop or ',
      htmlA('Select Files')
    )),
    style=list(
      'width'= '100%',
      'height'= '60px',
      'lineHeight'= '60px',
      'borderWidth'= '1px',
      'borderStyle'= 'dashed',
      'borderRadius'= '5px',
      'textAlign'= 'center',
      'margin'= '10px'
    ),
    # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
    multiple=TRUE
  ),
  htmlDiv(id='output-data-upload')
)))


parse_contents = function(contents, filename, date){
  content_type = strsplit(contents, ",")
  content_string = strsplit(contents, ",")
  decoded = base64_dec(content_string)
  
  if('csv' %in% filename){
    df = read.csv(utf8::as_utf8(decoded))
  } else if('xls' %in% filename){
    df = read.table(decoded, encoding = 'bytes')
  } else{
    return(htmlDiv(list(
      'There was an error processing this file.'
    )))
  }
  
  return(htmlDiv(list(
    htmlH5(filename),
    htmlH6(anytime(date)),
    dashDataTable(df_to_list('records'),columns = lapply(colnames(df), function(x){list('name' = x, 'id' = x)})),
    htmlHr(),
    htmlDiv('Raw Content'),
    htmlPre(paste(substr(toJSON(contents), 1, 100), "..."), style=list(
      'whiteSpace'= 'pre-wrap',
      'wordBreak'= 'break-all'
    ))
  )))
}

app$callback(
  output = list(id='output-data-upload', property = 'children'),
  params = list(input(id = 'upload-data', property = 'contents'),
                state(id = 'upload-data', property = 'filename'),
                state(id = 'upload-data', property = 'last_modified')),
  function(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates){
    if(is.null(list_of_contents) == FALSE){
      children = lapply(1:length(list_of_contents), function(x){
        parse_contents(list_of_contents[[x]], list_of_names[[x]], list_of_dates[[x]])
      })
      
    }
    return(children)
  })

app$run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem following the dashr example to use the [upload component](https://dashr.plotly.com/dash-core-components/uploadcomponent) to read a csv file. I detected a few lines that are not working properly, but I am still unabled to get a data-frame from the file in a staightforward way.

Regarding the error: **could not find function "base64_dec"**, I found that [jsonlite](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.7.0/topics/base64) package has a function "base64_dec" that seems to do what is intended. You can indicate the package when calling the function:

```
decoded = jsonlite::base64_dec(content_string)
```

Regarding the error: **non-character argument**, it is generated in this line when loading the app, because "contents" is still empty:

```
#This gives an error if run before reading the data
content_type = strsplit(contents, ",")
#Anyway that should be like below, because the content are given in a list and you want the first element
content_type = strsplit(contents, ",")[[1]][1]
```

Dash runs the callback at the begining of the app, but here we need the function to execute after selecting a file. Here the condition in the if statement is not doing its job:

```
#Will execute the code in the if even before selecting data:
if(is.null(list_of_contents) == FALSE)
#Will exectue only when data is selected
if(length(list_of_contents[[1]])>0)
```

The main issue is that when you have the decoded binary file, read.csv can't read it (at least not how it is in the example code given, because its input is the filename). Something that partially worked for me is this [readBin() example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-binary-files-in-r-programming/), but you need to be aware of the size of the table, which is not practical for my case, because it will be different every time.

This is the complete code I modified to solve the issues you found, but the core part of reading the CSV is not functional. I also modified the conditions to proceed if the file selected is a CSV of Excel file (because they were not working properly):

```
library(dashCoreComponents)
library(dashHtmlComponents)
library(dash)
library(anytime)

app <- Dash$new()

app$layout(htmlDiv(list(
  dccUpload(
    id='upload-data',
    children=htmlDiv(list(
      'Drag and Drop or ',
      htmlA('Select Files')
    )),
    style=list(
      'width'= '100%',
      'height'= '60px',
      'lineHeight'= '60px',
      'borderWidth'= '1px',
      'borderStyle'= 'dashed',
      'borderRadius'= '5px',
      'textAlign'= 'center',
      'margin'= '10px'
    ),
    # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
    multiple=TRUE
  ),
  htmlDiv(id='output-data-upload')
)))

parse_contents = function(contents, filename, date){
  print("Inside function parse")
  content_type = strsplit(contents, ",")[[1]][1]
  content_string = strsplit(contents, ",")[[1]][2]
  #print(content_string)
  decoded = jsonlite::base64_dec(content_string)
  #print(decoded)
  if(grepl(".csv", filename, fixed=TRUE)){
    print("csv file selected")
    ## Here a function to read a csv file from the binary data is needed
    ## Because read.csv asks for the file NAME.
    ## readBin() can read it, but you need to know the size of the table to parse properly
    #as.data.frame(readBin(decoded, character()))
    #df = read.csv(utf8::as_utf8(decoded))
  } else if(grepl(".xlsx", filename, fixed=TRUE)){
    ##Also to read the Excel
    df = read.table(decoded, encoding = 'bytes')
  } else{
    return(htmlDiv(list(
      'There was an error processing this file.'
    )))
  }
  
  return(htmlDiv(list(
    htmlH5(filename),
    htmlH6(anytime(date)),
    dashDataTable(df_to_list('records'),columns = lapply(colnames(df), function(x){list('name' = x, 'id' = x)})),
    htmlHr(),
    htmlDiv('Raw Content'),
    htmlPre(paste(substr(toJSON(contents), 1, 100), "..."), style=list(
      'whiteSpace'= 'pre-wrap',
      'wordBreak'= 'break-all'
    ))
  )))
}

app$callback(
  output = list(id='output-data-upload', property = 'children'),
  params = list(input(id = 'upload-data', property = 'contents'),
                state(id = 'upload-data', property = 'filename'),
                state(id = 'upload-data', property = 'last_modified')),
  function(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates){
    if(length(list_of_contents[[1]])>0){
      print("Inside if")
      children = lapply(1:length(list_of_contents), function(x){
        parse_contents(list_of_contents[[x]], list_of_names[[x]], list_of_dates[[x]])
      })
      return(children)
    }
    
  })

app$run_server()
```

I hope they revise this example to make it work.